# Angularjs ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been looking for a solution to using angulars built in filter with a different data set than that what is used for the ng-repeat but I haven't come across anything.

For example in this code snippet the filter would only be filtering data inside of `filteredPages` but the problem with this is that `filteredPages` is only the first page of paginated results, I want to filter the original data that `filteredPages` is created from.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="rate in filteredPages | filter:search | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse ">
        <td data-title="'location'">{{rate.location}}</td>
        <td data-title="'code'">{{rate.code}}</td>
        <td data-title="'peak_charge'">{{rate.charge_peak}}</td>
        <td data-title="'offpeak_charge'">{{rate.charge_offpeak}}</td>
       <td data-title="'connnection_charge'"> {{rate.connection_charge}}</td>
 </tr>
```

filteredPages

```
 $scope.$watch('currentPage', function () {
    //Define the pagination functionality....
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    $scope.filteredPages = $scope.list_data.slice(begin, end);

    return $scope.filteredPages;
});
```

`$scope.list_data` is the data I would like to filter through. `$scope.filteredPages` is the paginated result, so when using the filter it only searches the page that you are currently on.

ng-model search

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" ng-disabled="check" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter By">
</div>
```

Would I have to create my own filter or is there another way I can do it? 
If anyone has an idea on how I can achieve this, would  be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: _I want to filter the original data that `filteredPages` is created from._ Can you show us that as well

Comment: you have textbox or any other filter option ? what is that search in filter ?

Comment: @George added in to the question

Comment: @Shafeeque search is the textbox, have added that in to the question too

Comment: @Kyle Thanks, looks like your best option would be to use `$scope.list_data` as you repeater and create a custom filter then set them up like this `ng-repeat="rate in list_data | filter:search | currentPage: pageStartAndEnd | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse "` Either that or add a `ng-change` to the `search`

Comment: You have paginated data and but you want to search the whole set, not just the page? I think I have done this before.

Comment: @George thanks for reply, sorry I should have mentioned I have tried that way using `list_data` as the repeater but then it breaks the pagination

Comment: @KevinCaravaggio yes you put it much better than me, that is exactly what i need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed it by using `list_data` as the repeater and the built in [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter (Which allows a second parameter `begin`)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.list_data = [{item: '1'}, {item: '2'}, {item: '3'}, {item: '4'}, {item: '5'}, {item: '6'}, {item: '7'}, {item: '8'}, {item: '9'}, {item: '10'}, {item: '11'}, {item: '12'}, {item: '13'}, {item: '14'}, {item: '15'}];

  $scope.numPerPage = 5;
  $scope.begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
  $scope.end = $scope.begin + $scope.numPerPage;
  $scope.search = null;


  $scope.$watch('currentPage', function() {
    //Define the pagination functionality....
    $scope.begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    $scope.end = $scope.begin + $scope.numPerPage;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="rate in list_data | filter:search | limitTo:end:begin ">
        <td data-title="'location'">{{rate.item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've omitted the `orderBy` so don't forget to add it back in

Comment: Thank you, the filter works perfect! Although its created a small problem with pagination, it still works but rather than swapping the results when next page is clicked it appends them to the bottom

Comment: @Kyle That is strange, guess you can post it as another question if you have issues resolving it yourself

Comment: Will do,  I'm still an apprentice so I give myself an hour, hour and half and if i feel like I'm not getting anywhere I ask on here. Thanks for all your help @George

Answer (score 0):

Directive mash-up I used previously:
`ng-repeat="row in pageRows = (data | filter:search) | limitTo:itemsPerPage:itemsPerPage*(currentPage-1)"`

Where I defined some of the params in the JS side. I had the pagination bit integrated with ng bootstrap and used `uib-pagination`.